# How to check whether the entered text in the textbox is alphabet or number

Tags: c#

I need to check whether the enterd text in the textbox is number or alphabet and based on the condition should perform some action .
I have a list of items to display and the user can enter either the sequence number or an alphabet , based on the sorting should be done.

```
string id = userTextBox1.Text;
if (int.Parse(id) >= 0 && int.Parse(id) <= 9)


{

//action to be performed 


}
```

How can i check the condition whether the entered text is alphabet

Comment: Your int.Parse will fail on invalid input, use int.TryParse instead.

Comment: What do you mean by alphabet ? Only letters ? Only "non parsable to int" ?  By the way, you should rather use `int.TryParse` if you wanna avoid exceptions...

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(userTextBox1.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");`

Comment: This could have been done with a simple google search.

Comment: I have a list of items to display and the user can enter either the sequence number or an alphabet , based on the sorting should be done.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
using System.Linq;
//...    

if (id.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit))
{
   //action to be performed 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`, otherwise you're getting an exception if the input is invalid. Then this should work:

```
int number;
if(int.TryParse(userTextBox1.Text, out number))
{
    if(number >= 0 && number <= 9)
    {

    }
    else
    {
         // invalid range?
    }
}
else
{
    // not an integer -> alphabet? (or what does it mean)
}
```

If "alphabet" means only letters and no digits, you can use [`Char.IsLetter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// ...
else if(userTextBox1.Text.All(char.IsLetter))
{
    // alphabet? 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching something like this:

```
protected void Validate_AlphanumericOrNumeric(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex numeric = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]+$");
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex alphanemeric = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex alphabets = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[A-z]+$");
    string IsAlphaNumericOrNumeric = string.Empty;
    if (numeric.IsMatch(txtText.Text))
    {
        //do anything
    }
    else
    {
        if (alphabets.IsMatch(txtText.Text))
        {
            //do anything
        }
        else if (alphanemeric.IsMatch(txtText.Text))
        {
            //do anything
        }
    }



}
```

Based on your condition do your work

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isNumber = id.Select(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Sum(x => x? 0:1) == 0;
```

A very crude method, but it works.
We transform the text into a boolean List and sum depending on the value. If it's 0 we just have numbers in the string.
This does not work with a decimal point though.